# how do i pass multiple files as arguments in command line for python using regular expressions?

Tags: python, windows-7, command-line, tags, command-line-arguments

I'm not able to do this

> ptags.py *.py

or

> python *.py

i'm getting an error saying "Cannot open file named *.py"

but i'm able to open all the python files in vim using this command

> vim *.py

python 2.7 in windows 7 command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot using standard Windows `cmd` shell. You can use something like bash from Cygwin, maybe PowerShell.

If you want to open `*.py` from application like `vim` but in Python, then you can use `glob` module.

Comment: in case of vim, i was able to open multiple files like this... this isnt working just for python..

Comment: In Windows `cmd` it depends from application. Some use libraries like 'glob' in Python, while others do not :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the sensible behaviour would be for the interpreter to do when presented with more than one source file - If you just want it to execute all `.py` files in the current directory, then you should be explicit.

(Note - haven't done Windows command lines in a while, so this is OTTOMH):

```
for %i in (*.py) do python %i
```

On the other hand - if you're only executing a single source file, and want to expand out matches - then look at `glob` or `os.listdir` and co. and inside your code loop over that... something like:

```
import sys
from glob import glob

in_pattern = sys.argv[1]
for filenames in glob(in_pattern):
    print filename
```

Comment: the ptags.py program is able to handle multiple arguments.. its just that i'm not able to have all the files as arguments using *.py

Comment: i haven't tried glob.. but what you said makes sense.. instead i just used bash in cygwin.. somehow this is working in it..